# NodeJS app performance logs

Tags: node.js

Is there some kind of built in option, which will make nodejs log info about performance into a file.
Something like:

```
node --log-performance server.js
```

if not, then could you advice a tool, which will help me to get info about my app performance?

Comment: do want to save loggs ?

Comment: yes, i'd like to analyse them after stress test has been finished

Answer (score 0):

There are tools out there you can use to profile your application,

- [Basic Node docs way](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/)
- [look](https://github.com/baryshev/look)

[Here](http://www.willvillanueva.com/the-node-js-profiling-guide-that-hasnt-existed-profiling-node-js-applications-part-1/) is a nice blog explaining it all

If it is memory leaks that you want to find i just run the app on [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) and debug it using chrome DEV tools by taking a heap snapshot and analyzing it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a logging modules [**scribbles**](https://npmjs.com/package/scribbles) that you can drop in. That works similarly to Console.

**You would be interested in the [performance-monitoring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scribbles#performance-monitoring) feature.**

It will give you, out of the box

- state: *the state of the services. e.g. "up", "blocking"*
- cpu: *CPU info*

  - cores: *number of available cores*
  - model: *description of the processor*
  - speed: *MHz frequency speed*
  - percUsed: *load on process as percentage*
  - percFree: *available on process as percentage*
- sys: *System info*

  - startedAt: *when it's system was started*
  - arch: *platform architecture. e.g "x64"*
  - platform: *the operating system platform*
  - totalMem: *the total megabytes of memory being used*
  - freeMem: *the total megabytes of memory free*
  - usedMem: *the total megabytes of memory being used*
- process:

  - percUsedCpu: *the percentage of processing power being used by this process*
  - percFreeMem: *the percentage of memory being used by this process*
  - usedMem: *the total megabytes of memory being used by this process*
  - startedAt: *when it's process was started*
  - pTitle: *the current process title (i.e. returns the current value of ps)*
  - pid: *the ID of the process*
  - ppid: *the ID of the current parent process*
  - user: *node the name of the user who started node*
  - vNode: *version of node*
- network: *Networking info*

  - port: *listening on this Port*
  - connections: *number of current established connections*